# Speeding up code for (0,1) Matrix and Calculating Recurrent Rate (RQA analyses)

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I am trying for several days make this code faster. The function just takes a time series makes a Distance matrix of it and then compares components of it with Variance of that series and if component is smaller then Var, it substitutes it with 1 otherwise with 0.
I would like to use it on time series of length about 10000. F.e. `Dat = N[Table[Sin[x], {x, 1, 10000}]];`

My function is:

```
Rp[data_] := (
  Clear[rr, N1, RR, DD];
  rr = Variance[data];
  N1 = Length[data];
  RR = ConstantArray[0, {N1, N1}];
  DD = DistanceMatrix[data] ^2;

  For[i = 1, i < N1, i++,
                    For[j = 1, j < N1, j++,
    If[DD[[i, j]] <= rr, RR[[i, j]] = 1; RR[[j, i]] = 1, 
     RR[[j, i]] = 0; RR[[i, j]] = 0]

              ] 
   ];
  RR
  )
```

I have tried several options, substitute cycle with table and compile to c, but it didn't work better. This takes on my machine cca 10 min. I can run similar code on MATLAB like in 10 sec, where is the problem please, how to speed it up ?

Thank you guys for helping me, I didn't know I can use `UnitStep` on whole Matrix.

But actually my whole problem is to calculate from the output Reccurence Rate-RR which is part of RQA analysis, my code is

```
Rqa[RP_] := (

  Lmin = 2;
  N1 = Length[RP];
  Yout = Flatten[ConstantArray[0, {1, N1}]] ;

  For[k = 2, k < N1, k++,

                  Onn = 1; While[ Onn <= N1 + 1 - k,

    If[RP[[ Onn, Onn + k - 1]] == 1, A = 1; off = 0;

                              While[ off == 0 && Onn != N1 + 1 - k, 

                               If[RP[[Onn + 1, k + Onn]] == 1,
                                          A = A + 1; Onn = Onn + 1,
                              off = 1]
                              ];

                        Yout[[A]] = Yout[[A]] + 1;
                  ];
    Onn = Onn + 1;
    ]
   ];
  S = 2*Yout;
  SR = 0;
  For[i = 1, i < N1, i++,  
              SR = SR + i*S[[i]];];
  RR = SR/(N1*(N1 - 1))

  )
```

Which contains many loops and is also takes too much time, like 10 min for series of 10000 length = Input 10000*10000 matrix. From Michaels adviced topic I have read that I should replace For with Table ?  I am afraid this wont help like in previous example. Can you please give me some advice or built in function which can help me  ? I hope editing wont delete your comments.

Comment: Try `RR = UnitStep[rr - DistanceMatrix[data]^2]`.

Comment: Some advice about for loops: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you work on full matrices while the output matrix will be sparse, i.e., it contains mostly zeroes. That would be slow in *any* programming language. In particular, you don't need the full distance matrix. You were much better off by using `Nearest`.

```
idx = Nearest[data->Automatic,data,{∞,rr}][[All,2;;]];
```

should give you a list `idx` of lists so that `idx[[i]]` contains all indices `j` such that `R[[i,j]] == 1`. The matrix `R` is then best built with an undocumented way to create a `SparseArray`. The overall function `Rp` could look like this:

```
ClearAll[Rp];
Rp[data_] := Module[{rr, N1, idx, rp, ci},
  rr = Variance[data];
  N1 = Length[data];
  idx = Nearest[data -> Automatic, data, {∞, Sqrt[rr]}][[All,2 ;;]];
  rp = Join[{0}, Accumulate[Length /@ idx]];
  ci = Partition[Join @@ idx, 1];
  SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {N1, N1}, 
    0, {1, {rp, ci}, ConstantArray[1, Length[ci]]}}
  ]
```

For `data = N[Table[Sin[x], {x, 1, 10000}]];`, `Rp[data]` is computed in about two and a half seconds on my machine.

**Remark**

Unfortunately, I observed a bit too late that the the radius to pick data is basically the standard error of the dataset. Thus, the matrix is *not really* sparse so that the method is only marginally faster than J.M.'s proposal.

A slightly faster way (without `SparseArray` and employing less mysterious syntax) is obtained with the following function:

```
ClearAll[Rp2];
Rp2[data_] := Module[{rr, N1, idx, R},
  rr = Variance[data];
  N1 = Length[data];
  R = ConstantArray[0, {N1, N1}];
  idx = Nearest[data -> Automatic, data, {∞, Sqrt[rr]}][[All, 2 ;;]];
  MapIndexed[{x, y} \[Function] R[[y, x]] = 1, idx];
  R
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, already Michaels solution helped me with my problem, but actually I have find out this wasnt the only thing which was slovering  me, the point is I want to caluclate from previous output RR- reccurance rate, which is part of RQA analysis